# Cannot resolve symbol StyleSelector on a osmdroid application

Tags: android, osmdroid

I'm unable to find a way to overcome the error "cannot resolve symbol..." on the following :

- StyleSelector
- getFiles
- getLocalFile

on a android app .  I belive all above may bellong to the same import

```
import org.osmdroid.bonuspack.kml.StyleSelector;
```

Can anyone tell if is deprecated? and if so what is the replacement?

```
    HashMap<String, StyleSelector> styles = MapActivity.mKmlDocument.getStyles();
    styles.remove(mInitialStyleId);
    styles.put(newStyleId, mStyle);
    
    String iconHref = eIconHref.getText().toString();
    mStyle.mIconStyle.setIcon(iconHref, MapActivity.mKmlDocument.getLocalFile(), null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To correct this error one needs to upgrade the bobuspack like below:

In the build.gradle of your Project (top level), add the jitpack repository:

```
repositories { 
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

Then in the build.gradle of your app, add this dependency:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.github.MKergall:osmbonuspack:6.6.0'
}
```

Then set the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile(name:'osmbonuspack_v6.6.0', ext:'aar')
    compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.1.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.4'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
}
```